# Can't change a Custom DialogFragment layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

So reading through the Google API Guides I came across how to load a custom layout within an Alert Dialog Box [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout)

I wrote a class that extends a DialogFragment class like this:

```
    String product;
String description;
String company;
public void getAdInfo(String p, String d, String c)
{
    product = p;
    description = d;
    company = c;
}
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_dialog, null));
            TextView pt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.product);
            pt.setText(product);
            TextView dt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.description);
            dt.setText(description);
            TextView ct = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.company);
            ct.setText(company);
           builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // do something
               }
           });
           builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dismiss();
               }
           });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Here's the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
   />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/company"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
   />  
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
   />
```

I instanciate the Dialog within an OnClickListener with these lines.

```
AdDialogFragment ad = new AdDialogFragment();
                        ad.getAdInfo(j.getAttribute("product"), j.getAttribute("description"), j.getAttribute("company"));
                        ad.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
```

j being an element from an xml node.

When I click on the button that's supposed to run the dialog I get this NullPointerException error from LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10483):    at com.onix.mallard.android.guifrag.AdDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(AdDialogFragment.java:29)
```

The error refers to the line:

```
pt.setText(product);
```

Ultimately, it crashes the app completely. How can I change the layout of a DialogFragment dynamically? The Android API Guide says that DialogFragments are bound by the same lifecycle as Fragments, but that doesn't tell me much since they don't make use of FragmentTransactions (to my knowledge). If this is not possible and I need to instance the information as an Activity, no harm is done.

If it helps, the dialog is called from within a Fragment.

Comment: your getAdInfo() should be setAdInfo I think, tho that doesn't change much, but you're setting the values, not getting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue a while ago by instead of recurring to the AlertDialog class I used a regular Activity. In AndroidManifest.xml, the activity specification has the following line.

```
android:theme="@styles/Theme.HoloLight.Dialog"
```

A word of advice, Linear Layout doesn't work. Try RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would do that (untested code) ;)

Your custom Dialog:

```
public class AdDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
   String mProduct;
   String mDescription;
   String mCompany;
   TextView mProductTV;
   TextView mDescriptionTV;
   TextView mCompanyTV;

   public void setAdInfo(String product, String desc, String company)
   {
       mProduct = product;
       mDescription = desc;
       mCompany = company;
   }
   public AdDialogFragment() {
        super();
   }
   public static AdDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new AdDialogFragment();
   }

public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
   final View content = factory.inflate(R.layout.ad_dialog, null);
   mProductTV = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.product);
   mDescriptionTV = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.description);
   mCompanyTV = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.company);

   fillTextViews();

   AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.)); //can't remember the name or create a custom theme.
   } else {
      dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());//anything below honeycomb can die :).
   }

   //  now customize your dialog
   dialog.setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.some_title_if_any))
      .setView(content)
      .setCancelable(true) //this is the default I think.
      .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // do something
               }
           });
      .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dismiss();
               }
           });
   return dialog.create();
}

private void fillTextViews() {
   mProductTV.setText(mProduct);
   mDescriptionTV.setText(mDescription);
   mCompanyTV.setText(mCompany);
}
```

And this is how you call it from an Activity for example:

```
public void showYourFancyDialog() {
   AdDialogFragment dialog = AdDialogFragment.newInstance();
   dialog.setAdInfo(yourProduct, yourDescription, yourCompany);
   dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

<sub>Using patterns from [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)</sub>

Comment: I used your implementation. I used `dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "ad");` instead of the Support Manager because I'm calling it in a onClickListener. As it happens, LogCat throws this other error: `E/AndroidRuntime(1550): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application` After debugging it has to do with the aforementioned line of code. What to do?

Comment: That's probably a bad context, are you using the Activity's context? if you use ApplicationContext, you can't display a dialog (App Context can't touch the UI).

Comment: Also are you developing for HONEYCOMB and above only? Because getFragmentManager and getSupportFragmentManager are both accessible if you import the right packages (android.support.v4.app). What do you mean I'm calling this in an onClickListener? Anonymous inlined classes have a reference to the parent object.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following, it has worked for me:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_dialog, null));
builder.setView(v);
```

And then call `findViewById` like such:

```
v.findViewById();
```

Comment: To explain further, `getView` returns the view for the fragment, but you haven't set it yet. You're still in the process of creating it. So you should get the view directly as this answer describes.

Comment: Thanks @kabuko, I was actually wondering why `getView` hadn't worked for me and I just tried this and it had happened to work yesterday and so I went with it and didn't get around to looking up the reason. That helps this make more sense.

Comment: @TronicZomB not quite. Check Martin's response to this question. DialogFragment doesn't crash anymore, but still doesn't work.